# Retrieving states of multiple child components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm putting together a little game as an exercise in React.  There are a few options, you pick the one's you think are right, the game checks them and lets you know if you got it. How do I retrieve the state from the option buttons?  What is the "React way" of thinking about this?  Here is the parent:

```
class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.answerHandler = this.answerHandler.bind(this)
  }
  answerHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    // Get answer array, check answer??

  }
  render() {
    const optArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    return(
      <div>
        {optArr.map((opt, i) => <OptionButton opt={opt} key={i} />)}
        <AnswerButton answerHandler={this.answerHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The answer button:

```
class AnswerButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.answerHandler}>Submit Answer!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The option button:

```
class OptionButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected: false
    }
  }
  unselectSet() {
    this.setState({
      selected: false
    })
  }
  selectSet() {
    this.setState({
      selected: true
    })
  }
  toggler() {
    this.state.selected ? this.unselectSet() : this.selectSet()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.toggler()} style={numberButtonStyle}>{this.props.opt}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much better to store the state in the place where you're going to need it, rather than in the individual components and then retrieve it. So I'd do

```
class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.answerHandler = this.answerHandler.bind(this)
  }
  answerHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    // Get answer array, check answer??

  }
  handleOptionChange( event ) {
     //store the option state here, ready for when we need it
  }
  render() {
    const optArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    return(
      <div>
        {
           optArr.map(
             (opt, i) => <OptionButton 
                 opt={opt} 
                 key={i} 
                 onOptionChange={ this.handleOptionChange } 
            />)
        }
        <AnswerButton answerHandler={this.answerHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, seems so easy now that you say it.  Thanks!

Comment: I still have a question before accepting.  How do I manage the properties of the OptionButtons separately in the Game's state?  For instance, I could make an `isSelected` state in the Game, then pass it to the OptionButtons as a prop, but is there a way to handle them individually other than just having something like `isSelected1`, `isSelected2`, ..., `isSelected5` as states in the Game?  It seems like there would be a more dynamic way of doing this?

Comment: Make your state an array, or an object indexed by ids, so that when an option button updates you update the corresponding state.